# TS2305: Module "nostr-tools" has no exported member 'Event' Error in WebStorm but not in VSCode

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, webstorm

I am currently working on a TypeScript project in WebStorm 2023.3.2 and I have encountered an issue. When I import the Event member from the `nostr-tools` module, WebStorm shows an error:

> TS2305: Module "nostr-tools" has no exported member 'Event'.

However, when I open the same project in VSCode, there is no such error. I try it on my two computers but all have same problem.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it possible WebStorm is using its own version of TypeScript with a different `lib.d.ts`? Have you added `typescript` as project development dependency?

Comment: i added typescript as project development dependency

Comment: I'm afraid that we can’t investigate this problem without a sample project from your side. Errors come from the Typescript compiler service and thus are specific to the project configuration (`tsconfig.*.json` files), installed packages and the project structure.